# Cannot insert the value NULL into column BLAH table BLAH column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a domain entity that has

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

set on the `Id` property but EF is still trying to insert a null value when attempting to save it. Is this a common problem? This is an example of what it looks like.

```
public class Invoice
{   
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ShippingInformation ShippingInformation{ get; set; }
    public BillingInformation BillingInformation { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this Code First, or are you mapping to existing tables?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but it might be useful. Maybe a migration failed to set the database up properly to generate your key for you, and when you try to perform the update, neither EF nor the DB sets your key... https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/509

Comment: @Steve That was the problem! Thanks Steve! I had changed something in the entity that migrations didn't recognize so it was tweaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bug in the Entity Framework where migrations won't properly detect changes to `DatabaseGeneratedOption`.

See [this issue on the Entity Framework page on the Codeplex website](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/509) for a description of the problem and an example of how to recreate it.

Comment: I spent many hours trying to figure this out. I ended up with deleting all my tables and migrations and then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can add this attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`with key, it worked for me with entity framework 6.1.3.

For Example,

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
Public int EmployeeId  { get; set; }
```